# How to add credentials for googleapiclient on AppEngine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-platform, credentials

I am using Python Google API Client by following [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/python-client-library). I was able to run the API locally by downloading the credential JSON and running `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="[PATH]"`. Now, I would like to deploy my application that uses the API to AppEngine. How can I do so? Do I have to somehow download JSON on my AppEngine machine and run `export` via `app.yaml`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the JSON file inside your application directory and it will be deployed to GAE as part of your application. Then you can reference it in your app with just a file path (relative to the your `app.yaml` file). Easiest is to put it right beside your `app.yaml` file and reference it with just the filename, no file path.

The exact way to reference it may be depending on the GAE environment and runtime your app uses (which you didn't mention), exporting `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` via `app.yaml` may be right.

You may want to check your app's handlers and ensure that you don't accidentally respond with the JSON file to a properly crafted external request - you probably don't want that file served to an external request :)

Comment: Is it not too risky to push the json with the repo? I assume that you `gitignore` when pushing to GitHub?

Comment: @alpaca - Dan's answer is correct. However, I do not recommend storing or using credential files in App Engine. Instead, assign the correct permissions to the App Engine service account. Your code as written is using "ADC - Application Default Credentials" which will automatically use the App Engine service account if the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS is not used. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/access-control

Comment: @alpaca You can `gitignore` the file. That way it will not be included in the repo. However, when you do a `gcloud app deploy`, it gets pushed to the server and can be accessed by your app. If only one person deploys the app, then you won't need to worry about the key being omitted when others redeploy. 

A workaround for when multiple users will be doing  deployments is for each of them to have the file in their source folders.