# In GCP yaml file is there a way to include credentials instead of GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS linking a json file?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, yaml, google-cloud-storage

Trying to deploy to app engine for a dev site and would like to simply include GCP creds inside the app.yaml.

Is it somehow possible to include the creds instead of linking to yet another file?

```
env_variables:
  ...
  GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: './credentials/service-account.dev.json'
```

I've tried many things however it seems the next-best option is to setup Secret Manager to avoid this.

Comment: 1) You do not need to specify a service account at all. Use the service account assigned to App Engine. Your code can then use ADC to fetch credentials from metadata. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/service-account 2) Never, and I repeat never embed credentials in app.yaml 3) Automatic support for ADC is bulti-in to the Google Cloud SDK clients. 4) You do not need to set up Secret Manager to store service account credentials (chicken-and-egg, you need credentials to access Secret Manager). Secret Manager is a good product for secrets once you have initial credentials.

Comment: Hey John, thank you and yes I've read that page along with this one specifically: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/access-control#apps So I should focus on changing my default AE service's `permissions`? I cannot find any instruction on this.

Comment: Typically, you think in terms of **roles**. Roles bundle permissions together. The service account assigned to App engine is just like any other service account. Edit the role assignments using the CLI or the Google Cloud GUI. The link I provided has details on how to change service account permissions. This link also explains what a Default Service Account is with additional pages. https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#default

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can use a service account for the credential for app engine.

- service_account   Preview — Using user-managed service accounts for
  version-specific deployments

  This feature is covered by the Pre-GA Offerings Terms of the Google
  Cloud Terms of Service. Pre-GA features may have limited support, and
  changes to pre-GA features may not be compatible with other pre-GA
  versions. For more information, see the launch stage descriptions.
- Optional -The service_account element lets you specify a user-managed
  service account as the identity for the version. The specified
  service account will be used when accessing other Google Cloud
  services and executing tasks.

The service account must be provided in the following format:

```
service_account:
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME]@[PROJECT_ID].iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

[click here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/reference/app-yaml) for more documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look into this [authentication](https://googleapis.dev/python/google-api-core/latest/auth.html) document.

Also here is another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58055585/how-to-add-credentials-for-googleapiclient-on-appengine) you could find interesting.

Comment: Thank you @Vicente, however both those explain to use a "JSON keyfile and point to it using an environment variable" or to create a service account to reach out to for creds. I do see a helpful comment: "assign the correct permissions to the App Engine service account." perhaps I can skip these env vars and add them to my AE account.